# Flutter: should app/build folder and files be included on git ignore?

Tags: android, git, flutter, dart, gitignore

So I added a few packages today to my app:

advance_pdf_viewer: ^2.0.0
photo_view: ^0.11.1
webview_flutter: ^2.0.8
just_audio: ^0.7.5

and from that, over 500 files are waiting to be committed to git.
Most files are located in android/app/build/generated/.... or android/app/build/intermediates/....

Should these be ignored, deleted or committed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All `build` folders should be ignored